# Use Windows 10 firewall with third party antivirus

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, anti-virus, windows-firewall

I have a Windows 10 computer and am planning to buy antivirus software (Bitdefender antivirus plus).

However, this one does not include a firewall. So my question is can I install this antivirus software and use Windows' (Windows Defender I think?) firewall along with it?

Will the Windows firewall automatically turn on when it sees the antivirus software I'm installing doesn't have one?

This might be a very beginner question, thank you!

Comment: Windows Defender is the built-in Anti-Virus not the firewall.  Windows Firewall is the firewall.  Only another firewalls would disable Windows Firewalls

Comment: The firewall in Windows 10 is called "Windows Defender Firewall". It's enabled by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing third-party antivirus software that does not include its own firewall will **not** disable Windows' built-in firewall. In this case you can (and should) continue using the Windows firewall.

You might be asking this question because the Windows firewall is now called the Windows *Defender* firewall. However, it's not actually an integral part of the Windows Defender antivirus/anti-malware software. The Windows firewall existed long before Windows defender...it actually hails all the way back from the days of Windows XP.

> Will the Windows firewall automatically turn on when it sees the antivirus I'm installing doesn't have one?

The Windows firewall is on by default, so unless you intentionally disable it or install a security software program that does so, it will be enabled and protecting your computer.